# What does the logical OR do in following php code

Tags: php

```
if($post_id === null) {
    $this->db->insert($data);
    !isset($data[$this->page_id]) || $data[$this->page_id] = NULL;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logical operators perform **[short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)**. 
If the first part of a logical OR is true, the whole expression is true and hence, there is no need to evaluate the second part.

What it is doing is equivalent to:

```
if(isset($data[$this->page_id])){
    $data[$this->page_id] = NULL
}
```

To give an example of how this works, from the **[documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)**:

```
// foo() will never get called as those operators are short-circuit
$a = (false && foo());
$b = (true  || foo());
```